# How to debug what PHP PDO prepared statement does not insert data

Tags: php, pdo

I have

```
$salt = md5(mt_rand());
$hashed = hash_hmac('SHA256', $password, $salt);
$stmt = self::$_dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO users (username, password, salt, display, email) VALUES (:username, :password, :salt, :display, :email)');
$stmt->bindParam('username', $username);
$stmt->bindParam('password', $hashed);
$stmt->bindParam('salt', $salt);
$stmt->bindParam('display', $display);
$stmt->bindParam('email', $email);
$stmt->execute();
$firephp->log('Insert OK ');
if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
    return array(
            'status' => 'OK',
            'message' => 'Registration Successful'
    );
} 
$firephp->log('Unknown ... Row count: ' . $stmt->rowCount());
return array(
        'status' => 'failed',
        'message' => 'Something went wrong with the registration ... Please try again ...'
);
```

I always gets "Something went wrong with the registration ... Please try again ...". It appears `rowCount` is 0. True enough, it does not insert into database.  Why is that?

Comment: <strike>You missed an `else` I guess. The last `$firephp->log` call get always (unconditionally) executed</strike>. Nevermind, misread it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
 $firephp->log(
       $stmt->debugDumpParams()
       . "\n"
       . var_export($stmt->errorInfo());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put colons in the bindParam placeholders, like instead of

```
$stmt->bindParam('username', $username);
```

Do

```
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: That's a colon, not a semi-colon.

Comment: LOL, sorry for that... Fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

Similar problems can occur when someone turns/leaves off the DB autoincrement on the main id field.  Review the database and make sure it's set up properly.